# How to use the Android mobile fingerprint dialog on scan fingerprint

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to use mobile default fingerprint dialog screen when there is fingerprint enable in Xamarin. Android native app then the dialog for fingerprint scan should be the device dialog's don't want to use custom dialog .so how I can achieve this functionality in Xamarin. Android.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , add the permission in `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

**In code behind**

```
public class MyAuthCallbackSample : FingerprintManagerCompat.AuthenticationCallback
    {
        // Can be any byte array, keep unique to application.
        static readonly byte[] SECRET_BYTES = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        // The TAG can be any string, this one is for demonstration.
        static readonly string TAG = "xxx";

        public MyAuthCallbackSample()
        {
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManagerCompat.AuthenticationResult result)
        {
            if (result.CryptoObject.Cipher != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Calling DoFinal on the Cipher ensures that the encryption worked.
                    byte[] doFinalResult = result.CryptoObject.Cipher.DoFinal(SECRET_BYTES);

                    // No errors occurred, trust the results.              
                }
                catch (BadPaddingException bpe)
                {
                    // Can't really trust the results.
                   
                }
                catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ibse)
                {
                    // Can't really trust the results.
                   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // No cipher used, assume that everything went well and trust the results.
            }
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticationError(int errMsgId, ICharSequence errString)
        {
            // Report the error to the user. Note that if the user canceled the scan,
            // this method will be called and the errMsgId will be FingerprintState.ErrorCanceled.
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticationFailed()
        {
            // Tell the user that the fingerprint was not recognized.
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId, ICharSequence helpString)
        {
            // Notify the user that the scan failed and display the provided hint.
        }
    }

    public class CryptoObjectHelper
    {
        // This can be key name you want. Should be unique for the app.
        static readonly string KEY_NAME = "com.xamarin.android.sample.fingerprint_authentication_key";

        // We always use this keystore on Android.
        static readonly string KEYSTORE_NAME = "AndroidKeyStore";

        // Should be no need to change these values.
        static readonly string KEY_ALGORITHM = KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmAes;
        static readonly string BLOCK_MODE = KeyProperties.BlockModeCbc;
        static readonly string ENCRYPTION_PADDING = KeyProperties.EncryptionPaddingPkcs7;
        static readonly string TRANSFORMATION = KEY_ALGORITHM + "/" +
                                                BLOCK_MODE + "/" +
                                                ENCRYPTION_PADDING;
        readonly KeyStore _keystore;

        public CryptoObjectHelper()
        {
            _keystore = KeyStore.GetInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
            _keystore.Load(null);
        }

        public FingerprintManagerCompat.CryptoObject BuildCryptoObject()
        {
            Cipher cipher = CreateCipher();
            return new FingerprintManagerCompat.CryptoObject(cipher);
        }

        Cipher CreateCipher(bool retry = true)
        {
            IKey key = GetKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            try
            {
                cipher.Init(CipherMode.EncryptMode, key);
            }
            catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e)
            {
                _keystore.DeleteEntry(KEY_NAME);
                if (retry)
                {
                    CreateCipher(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.Exception("Could not create the cipher for fingerprint authentication.", e);
                }
            }
            return cipher;
        }

        IKey GetKey()
        {
            IKey secretKey;
            if (!_keystore.IsKeyEntry(KEY_NAME))
            {
                CreateKey();
            }

            secretKey = _keystore.GetKey(KEY_NAME, null);
            return secretKey;
        }

        void CreateKey()
        {
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.GetInstance(KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmAes, KEYSTORE_NAME);
            KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenSpec =
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyStorePurpose.Encrypt | KeyStorePurpose.Decrypt)
                    .SetBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                    .SetEncryptionPaddings(ENCRYPTION_PADDING)
                    .SetUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .Build();
            keyGen.Init(keyGenSpec);
            keyGen.GenerateKey();
        }
    }
```

In the activity

```
const int flags = 0; /* always zero (0) */

// CryptoObjectHelper is described in the previous section.
CryptoObjectHelper cryptoHelper = new CryptoObjectHelper();

// cancellationSignal can be used to manually stop the fingerprint scanner. 
var cancellationSignal = new Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal();

FingerprintManagerCompat fingerprintManager = FingerprintManagerCompat.From(this);

               
FingerprintManagerCompat.AuthenticationCallback authenticationCallback = new MyAuthCallbackSample();

// Start the fingerprint scanner.
fingerprintManager.Authenticate(cryptoHelper.BuildCryptoObject(), flags, cancellationSignal, authenticationCallback,null);
```

For more details you could check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fingerprint-authentication/) .

Comment: Fingerprint working fine but the issue with dialog some device double dialog appear one is my custom dialog and other one is the device full screen dialog .i one to show only when or when user click the device cancel button then my custom dialog also close  @Lucas Zhang - MSFT

Comment: It's up to device and different Android system .In your case you could better to set a custom dialog instead of the system default style .